# Is it possible to create custom filter to search for a tag on a few / selected sites?

Tags: support

At this moment I'm mostly looking for the questions and answers connected to `ffmpeg` tag.

Most of them are here, on `superuser.com`, but I can also see them on the other sites like `video.stackexchange.com` or `stackoverflow.com`. I've created some custom search filter which can show me questions tagged with `ffmpeg` sorted by their recent activity but this filter has no option to include more than one site to search on.

Do I really need to create and check three separate filters (and have three tabs open in my browser) if I would like to find the questions connected to `ffmpeg` on these three sites? I'd like to have them sorted in one place but I can't find the option to have that. I've already tried to use the [general search](https://stackexchange.com/search) but it seems to not offer any custom search filter with some kind of sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create Filters on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/filters) and filter for questions on specific sites

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems to work, but I have another problem: I've created a few filters to test this feature, in the end I want only one filter to be visible on the list but now I can't delete the additional ones. When I click "delete this filter" it does not delete the filter from the list of filters, it just resets the rules of the filter and resets its name: https://i.imgur.com/Nr882uJ.png - how I can have only one filter on the list? Is this some bug?

Comment: I've just noticed this global filter on Stack Exchange does not display all questions. For example: there are some recently closed questions with FFmpeg tag on Super User - they are displayed by my FFmpeg filter on Super User but they are not on this global search. Is there any way to fix that?